# XLS file downloads without file extension

Tags: excel, file, google-chrome, browser, download

I have a third party integration on a website and part of it is a downloadable Excel file. When downloading the file, there seems to be no file extension which results in the computer not knowing to which program the file should be opened with. If the extension is added manually it works just fine. This happens at least with Chrome on OSX.

I'm having trouble understanding where the problem is. Is it somehow possible to configure the server to add the file extension or is the problem in the browsers settings? Or is the only solution to ask the third party that serves the file to do something about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to fix wherever the browser is hitting to get this file. If it's your server (e.g. you're proxying the file from this 3rd party), then you need to do the fix. if the browser hits the 3rd party directly, they need to fix it. After all, there is NOTHING your server can do to tell the OTHER server what it should be doing.

Comment: Thank you for quick answer. The download link has an attribute onClick to a function which is defined in javascript file that is served by the third party. That function creates the file from a table that is in the same page and is also served by the third party. If I understand correctly, I could create my own function that does the same thing, but with proper file extension?

Comment: no idea. you'd have to show what this function does, but generally filenames are set by the `Content-disposition` header in the response from the server, and there's nothing you can really do in the REQUEST to tell the browser what the filename WILL be - except by mangling the url. most browsers will try to parse a filename out of the url if the responding server doesn't include a filename in the disposition header.